Existence and injectivity of a map from $\mathrm{Num}(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{C}$ to $H^1(X,\Omega^1_X)$
I am currently reading a paper by Mustata and Popa on the Van de Ven theorem, you can read the paper here.
On page 51 there is the following map
$$\alpha_\mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Num}(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{C} \hookrightarrow H^1(X,\Omega^1_X)$$ where $X$ is a projective variety, $\mathrm{Num}(X)$ is the group of divisors on $X$ up to numerical equivalence and $\Omega^1_X$ its cotangent bundle.
I would like to understand where this map comes from. Here is what I already know:

$\mathrm{Num}(X)$ is a quotient of $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$
$\mathrm{Pic}(X) \cong H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)$
The map \begin{align*}\mathrm{d}(\log):\mathcal{O}^*_X&\longrightarrow\Omega^1_X \\ f&\longmapsto f^{-1}\mathrm{d}f\end{align*} induces a well defined map $c : H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X) \to H^1(X,\Omega^1_X).$


The map $c$ associates to a line bundle its first Chern class. It is well-known (and easy) that it factors through numerical equivalence.

@abx Do you have a reference for that?
